# How To Redirect Browser To New URL in Robotframework After Working on Old URL without Closing Browser

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, robotframework

I'm working on a simple project where I launch chrome browser and perform operation on website #1 and once I have done that I logout from website #1 and now I want to launch website #2 on same browser. For e.g.

Step - 1 - Launch facebook and login to it

Step - 2 - Now launch twitter and login to it

```
*** Variables ***
${URL1}     http://www.facebook.com
${URL2}     http://www.twitter.com

*** Keywords ***
# 1st Login to facebook
    Open Browser    ${URL1}    chrome
    Login To Facebook

# 2nd Login to twitter
    Open Browser    ${URL2}    chrome
    Login To Twitter

# Now close the browser
    Close Browser
```

**Question** - *Which keyword can I use so that I after Login to Facebook keyword I can change the URL to twitter and then login to twitter and then close the browser ? Which is a better way to open a new tab with twitter or use the same tab and change the URL only.*

**Please Note :-**

With above mentioned code, a new window is opened with, but I don't    want that, all I want to achieve is to change the URL of the existing    opened browser window.

Comment: The question you pose suggests that you have not spent sufficient time reading the [SeleniumLibrary keyword documentation](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html). The [short cut section](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Shortcuts) provides easy access to the keywords specific documentation. This would have answered your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `Go To` keyword:

```
Go To    ${URL2}
```